# Is there a word for asking someone to hold onto something for you

Tags: single-word-requests

If I were to ask someone to hold onto something so I don't lose it, is there a word for that?

Comment: Or "May I entrust you with [sth] ?", noting that [sth] might be a belonging, a secret or a mission.

Answer (score 2):

There are several phrases such as 'look after' and 'take care of' but a single word is

> **mind**
>
> to take care of someone or something
> *Could you mind my bag for a moment?*

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mind).

Comment: I suppose 'bank' is a little different. // In the UK, 'Can you mind X, please?' in this sense implies (the strongly suggests _or_ the demands sense) a limited-time favour. There's also the general 'tend / look after': 'I have to mind the shop now Brian has left.'

Answer (score 0):

[https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/safekept#:~:text=safekept%20%2D%20Wiktionary%2C%20the%20free%20dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/safekept#:%7E:text=safekept%20%2D%20Wiktionary%2C%20the%20free%20dictionary)

Verb - safekept - simple past and past participle of safekeep

https://eng.ichacha.net/zaoju/safekeep.html

"Flashing between excitement and paranoia, Hevlin abruptly leaves, asking the player to safekeep the map."

Also, **safekeeping**

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/safekeeping

"I left my watch with Helen for safekeeping while I swam."

Comment: The noun **safekeeping** is _much_ more common that the verb **safekeep**, which is a rare back-formation from the noun.